ArcGIS Experience filtering multi select list
I'm using ArcGIS Experience Builder to make a set of dashboards for some data. I have a couple of graph widgets and a list widget to help display this data.
I have set up Actions on these widgets, so that if areas of the charts are selected, the data in the other charts and list update to only show the relevant data, which works great.
However, I have set up my list to be a multi select list, with the desire that users can select multiple different items in the list, to then help the filtering in the charts. When doing this, I don't want the data to be filtered in the list. This seems to be what is happening at the moment, because as soon as I select an item in the list, all the other items disappear so I cannot select anything else. If I'm quick, I can get a couple of items to select before they disappear, but this isn't what I want to happen.
I'm assuming I've either set up my list widget wrong, or the action on this widget or the other widgets, but I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to get this configured.
I've used ArcGIS Dashboards before and not had this issue with multi select, but I'm trying to get this to work in Experience Builder instead.
